# Naming conventions for nested collections in Java?

Tags: java, collections, naming-conventions

I have my own naming convention for nested collections where I use the plural-s multiple times, but I suspect this would confuse others, so is there a common naming convention for such a case?

```
List<List<List<Ball>>> ballsss;

for(List<List<Ball>> ballss: ballsss)
{
  for(List<Ball> balls: ballss)
  {
    for(Ball ball: balls)
    {
     ball.throw();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Isn't this primarily opinion based? and maybe case sensitive, too

Comment: Tacking on multiple `s`s destroys readability. What does the top level  collection actually represent/model?

Comment: It seems weird to have such a data structure in the first place. Maybe some dedicated model classes are in order.

Comment: Ask yourself the question: if you have a list of lists of lists of balls, does the name `ballsss` _really_ represent a _good_ name for that collection? What's the semantics/meaning of that list? I guess that you can come up with a better name (from a design point of view) which actually provides information on what that list means. (Assuming those 3 lists represent some 3d volume then better names could be `ballVolume`, `ballLayer`, `ballLine` etc.)

Comment: Indeed, this isn't a naming issue, this is a design issue.